# Invent custom filename extension for derived format

Tags: programming-practices, conventions

Say I use a predefined serialization format X for certain data. Should I indicate the application in a custom filename extension or not? It is quite common

- pk3 is a zip archive
- XSL, SVG and many others are XML files
- Some files are INI files

It is practical to denote the purpose of the file, but

- I am unhappy to invent another filename extension (there are already too many)
- It hides the fact that the user can use any program that can read and write X can be used to manipulate data (obfuscation)

I am interested in what is recommended in the following scenarios:

1. Program configuration data
2. Input files for code generation scripts
3. Saved program state
4. Plug-in bundle zip archive

Comment: Can you tell us more about your specific use case? There are pros & cons to both approaches and no one can really say without having some details.

Comment: Invent a new one and don't restrict yourself to three characters.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Would you say, there is no upper limit

Comment: @user877329 Most of mine are 10-20 characters. That's usually enough for a meaningful unique name (e.g. `.FirefoxPlugin`, `.MsExcelSheet`)

Comment: What do you want to happen when a Windows user double clicks on your file? A custom file extension in that case makes it easy to launch your application.

Comment: If it's used internally by your application I don't see any reason not to use meaningful extensions. If it's made so that people can, using external programs, modify the file then the basic extension (eg, .zip for a zip) should be used so that they know what they're modifying. There are some exceptions like having a .config for a config file when it could just be .txt, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: @Brandin. That's true. But not all user likes to clutter their registry. If the program is removed, there will be an invalid key left.

Comment: @user877329 I meant as a way of distinguishing which applications. For example, if you just name your file "foo.xml" then when I double click it it will probably launch my normal text editor. To associate it with your application, I would have to adopt my own convention such as foo.xyz (where xyz is something I made up). If you think of xyz already for the user, it becomes standardized.

Comment: @user877329 Then offer the user a choice in the installer program or within the application itself. It is customary to ask something like "Associate MyApp with .xyz?" and the user picks yes/no.